# Click Image By Phone Camera and set to ImageView in Original Quality

Tags: android, listview, android-camera

i tried to set on imageview with original quality but the image get compressed.
please help me to set image in imageview with original quality.

```
ImageView imageView;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
Bitmap photo;



  uploadImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
           startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

       }
   });


  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
        if(data!=null) {
            photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `glide`

Comment: Please show me the code

Comment: below is the code, hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using glide, first in your gradle add dependency

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide.3.7.0'
```

**And** use this code to get capture images

```
values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
            imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_RESULT);
```

And then in `onActivityResult`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {

        case PICTURE_RESULT:
            if (requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT)
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    try {
                        thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                                getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                        imgView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                        imageurl = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);

    Imageview imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view); 

 Glide.with(this).load(imageurl).into(imageView); 


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
        }
    }
```

And to get the path of image

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Comment: PICTURE_RESULT is not resolving.Its showing Red @Abdul

Comment: just declare int PICTURE_RESULT = 5; in your class